Not able to Program STM8S003F3
I am trying to program my STM8S003F3P6 in a custom board, the schematic below, using an ST-Link, but constantly get an error message while using STVP saying 'Cannot Communicate with the Device'. The same design works in another board though. Can't figure out what is wrong, have checked the Vcc/Gnd and it seems okay.


Your cap on NRST is pretty big.

I tried removing it but even then didnt work
